# In tf.function, how to convert dynamic tensor shape getted by tf.shape() to python values but not tensors itself?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a padded batch from tf.dataset, because every padded batch's shape is not fixed.So I have to use tf.shape method to get the dynamic shape of padded batch.The question is how can I convert the tensor shape getted by tf.shape to python values under tf.function?

```
@tf.function
def train_step(padded_batch):
    shape = tf.shape(padded_batch)
    x = np.zeros(shape[0], shape[1])
```

As the above code, I want to create a numpy array as the same shape of padded_batch，but 'shape' is a tensor, it can't be used directly in numpy.If there is someway to convert tensor to python values under tf.function.

The tensorflow version I use is tf2.0

Comment: Did this help? If not, please tell me what is missing. If yes, please upvote/accept as is expected in this "community".

Answer (score 2):

assuming you have a tensor named `a_tensor`:

```
this_is_a_regular_non_tensor_shape = a_tensor.shape.as_list()
```

(BTW: you don't seem to be using `np.zeros` correctly...you need to pass the shape as a single tuple/list argument. Not separate arguments for each dimension. For instance:

```
shape = padded_batch.shape.as_list()
x = np.zeros(shape)
```

Hope that helps.)

Comment: shape property is for static shape, I use tf.shape to get dynamic shape of dynamic batch. Returned by tf.shape is a tensor, it doesn't have as_list method.

Comment: But the dynamic shape isn't defined until session running, so I don't understand what you expect. Unless you mean that you have a None in some dimensions (for instance the batch dimension), for which case my solution works fine in my experience.

Comment: Yes, the padded batch has None dimension, So I have to get its dynamic shape for further work.I use the tf.function to switch to graph mode, the question is I don't know how to get the dynamic shape under tf.function.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [TF documents](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape),

> within **@tf.function** or within a compat.v1 context, not all dimensions
> may be known until execution time. Hence when defining custom layers
> and models for graph mode, prefer the dynamic **tf.shape(x)** over the
> static x.shape

Your code was ok. I just replaced np.zeros with tf.zeros. The @tf.function decorator means the code will run in **graph mode**. numpy is not allowed within graph. Tested in TF 2.x.

```
@tf.function
def train_step(padded_batch):
    shape = tf.shape(padded_batch)
    return tf.zeros((shape[0], shape[1]))
```